# Echo/print variables in a session array of codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to write a code where I use this particular line of code to store my post values in a session array

```
$this->session->set_userdata('newdata', $newdata);
```

The problem is, I can not seem to echo out the values inside it.

This is how I echo them out:

```
<?php echo $this->session->userdata('suffix'); ?>
```

Is there another way to echo out sessions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set data like this:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('newdata', $newdata);
```

You will need to access it like this:

```
$this->session->userdata('newdata');
```

So you could do:

```
// dump all content
var_dump($this->session->userdata('newdata'));

// or access array indexes like so.
$post_array = $this->session->userdata('newdata');
echo $post_array['index'];
```

Comment: how to display it in view page that session value

Answer (score 6):

Use this

```
$session_data = $this->session->all_userdata();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($session_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be an array so you cant display the contents using `echo`. use `print_r()` for displaying the array.

Comment: He is trying to echo not the whole session, but only a specific element, which, most likely, will be a string, but who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are taking data from a text box named "username", then you can print the session variable data in the following way :

```
$uname=$this->input->post('username'); //uname is the variable storing the user input.

$this->session->set_userdata('uname',$uname); //setting session variable assigning name as "uname".

echo $this->session->userdata('uname'); // echoing session data
```